# Suppose $0\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\to A \cong \Bbb{Z}^r\times T\to B\cong \Bbb{Z}^r\times T\to X\to 0$ is an exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves, exact-sequence

Let $r$ be a positive integer, and $T$ be a finite group.
Let $A,B$ be abelian groups which satisfies $A\cong \Bbb{Z}^r\times T$ and $B\cong \Bbb{Z}^r\times T$.

Suppose $0\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\to A\to B\to X\to 0$ is an exact sequence.

From these ingredients, can we conclude that $X\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ ?

In the case $r=0$, by applying isomorphism theorem to $A\to B$, we can definitely say order of $X$ is $2$, so the above claim is true.

But in general case, I don't have a confident to say order of $X$ is $2$.

The background of this question came when I was studying elliptic curves.
p$350$ of Silverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a number field and $A=E(K), B=E'(K)$, middle map in the exact sequence is $\phi :A\to B$, which is an isogeny of degree 2. $r=rank(E/K)$ and $T\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: No.  Take $T=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.  In the middle map, kill off the $T$ part of $A$, and embed the $\Bbb{Z}^r$ part of $A$ into a proper subgroup of the $\Bbb{Z}^r$ part of $B$.

Comment: @Chad K. What kind of condition on  $f$ ensures $\#X=2$ do you think ?

Comment: This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list; otherwise it will be bumped up periodically. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ can be identified uniquely inside $A$ as the subgroup of torsion elements of $A$ (i.e. finite order.)  Let's call it $T_A$.  In the short exact sequence
$$0\to T_A\to A\to A/T_A \to 0$$
the group $A/T_A\cong \Bbb{Z}^r$ is a free group.  It follows that the short exact sequence splits, and we can find a direct summand $A_0\subseteq A$ such that $A = A_0 \oplus T_A$ and $A_0\cong \Bbb{Z}^r$.  (Note: $A_0$ unlike $T$ is not uniquely identified inside $A$.)

Let $\sigma$ be the middle map.  Torsion elements must map to torsion elements, so $\sigma(T_A)\subseteq T_B$ where $T_B$ is the torsion subgroup of $B$ (which is also isomorphic to $T$).

Now we consider $\sigma\rvert_{A_0}$.  Since $\ker \sigma$ has $2$ elements and $A_0$ is torsion-free, it follows that $\ker \sigma\rvert_{A_0} = 0$, so $\sigma$ maps $A_0$ injectively into $B$.  Moreover, $\sigma(A_0)$ is torsion-free, so $\sigma(A_0)\cap \sigma(T_A) = 0$.  The subgroup $\sigma(A_0)$ of $B$ is a free subgroup of rank $r$.  The subgroup $\sigma(T_A)$ of $T_B$ must have index $2$, because $|T_A| = |T_B| = |T|$ and $\ker \sigma\rvert_{T_A}$ has $2$ elements.

So now, the only thing remaining is whether $\sigma(A_0)\oplus T_B = B$.  If they're equal then $X\cong T(B)/\sigma(T_A)$ so $|X|=2$.  If they're not equal then $(B/T_B) / ((\sigma(A_0)\oplus T_B)/T_B)$ is some finite group of size $N>1$ and $|X| = 2N$.

It is possible of course for $\sigma(A_0)\oplus T_B$ to be a proper subgroup of $B$.  If we start out with map $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(A_0)\oplus T_B = B$, we can take a basis for $A_0$, and then for some basis element $e$, alter $\sigma$ so that it maps $e$ to $2\sigma(e)$ instead of $\sigma(e)$.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the phrase in your comment: "if the middle map maps the free part of $A$ onto the free part of $B$ it's like the case $r=0$ by restricting the middle map to $T$ inside A- so $X$ must be a $2$-element as well."

Do you mean that if the middle map $\sigma$ does not alter $r$, that is, if $\sigma(A)$ has rank $r$, then $X$ always has order $2$?

Comment: @Pont:  That statement was imprecise.  There is no uniquely defined 'free part'.  'free part' refers to any direct summand of the torsion, but it's not unique, so there is no sense in saying that $\sigma$ maps $A_0$ onto 'the free part' of $B$.  $A_0$ and $\sigma(A_0)$ are always both free of rank $r$.  $\sigma(A)$ is not free, because it includes $\sigma(T_A)$ which is half of $T_B$.